# jquery-ajax-php comments form spam prevention (is such measure reasonable?)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, spam-prevention

Main page

```
$_SESSION['uniqid_mt_rand'] = uniqid(mt_rand(), true);
```

Then input form

```
<input name="hidden_field" type="hidden" id="hidden_field" 
value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars( $_SESSION['uniqid_mt_rand'] , ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");?>">
```

Then with `$.post("_record_comments.php" ....` send to `_record_comments.php`

And in `_record_comments.php` check if

```
$_SESSION['uniqid_mt_rand'] == $_POST['hidden_field']
```

Does it help to prevent something? As understand in this case I can be sure, that form is filled from website. So if bot send 'form' `$_POST` and `$_SESSION` would not be the same?

Comment: Look at [CSFR](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Site-Request-Forgery) - not your invention but you're quite close :-)

Comment: As @AxelAmthor noted, this looks more like CSRF protection, which serves a different (but arguably more important) purpose. You might look into [form honeypot fields](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3622433/1093087), as that is aimed more directly at spam prevention.

Comment: Seems this text http://nedbatchelder.com/text/stopbots.html is useful