# How to put IF condition for input field in a contact form (PHP, CODEIGNITER)

Tags: php, codeigniter

PHP Controller:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('phone', $this->language->get_text('phone', 'global'), 'max_length[0]');
```

I need to put an IF condition for the above line code to return this:

```
if (The_Above_Line_Code is NOT empty)
{
$this->output->set_status_header(400);
exit;
}
```

So, if the input field don't contain characters it's OK and the contact form to work properly, but if contain characters, then should return a blank page (set_status_header(400)).

*PS: It's a way to combat spam in contact form.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('phone', $this->language->get_text('phone', 'global'), 'max_length[0]|numeric');
```

If it's not a number then form validation fails. I don't see the logic in serving a 400.

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html?highlight=form%20validate#rule-reference

---

Update

After understanding your reasoning better you can simply do this:

```
if (!empty($this->input->post('phone'))) {
    show_404(); // sets header + exits
}
```

You can even use `show_404()` (CI function) as a way to log the error: `show_404('bot detected', true);`.

Comment: Alex, this input field is not a phone field. It is a "blank and hidden" field ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3622433/how-effective-is-the-honeypot-technique-against-spam ).  What i've implement WORKS pretty good, but i wish to implement what i wrote above. When a bot put any type of string in that field to return 400 error code not the reload the page contact. This field is hidden through CSS.

Comment: ahhh ok makes alot more sense. what threw me off was the form validation.

Comment: Thanks for the updated!
That is what i need. Cheers!