# Is this junk input, from a bot filling up a form on my website, safe?

Tags: php, security, email, spam-prevention, email-spam

So I use PHP and have a contact form on my website.
Once users fill up the form and submit, it will shoot an email to me.
I have been receiving junk input from bot, I assume, like below.
This is the result of `print_r($_REQUEST)`. I removed some parameter for simplicity.

```
Array
(
   [name] => rycpufrwq
   [email] => raaszg@fqhzdm.com
   [company] => naCuklaLMab
   [website] => http://ujpbfhazkpzv.com/
   [message] => cBimwx  <a href=\"http://pxlahgqmdrhs.com/\">pxlahgqmdrhs</a>, [url=http://sjmbrhkycvbz.com/]sjmbrhkycvbz[/url], [link=http://rddqwgzwvrhv.com/]rddqwgzwvrhv[/link], http://csohvhsvdisc.com/
)
```

On such request, I don't write to db or anything. I only send an email by calling `mail()`.
Specifically, `mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers)` where $headers is:

```
$headers="From:$email_from\r\nBcc:$email_bcc\r\nReply-To:$name<$email>\r\n";
```

$name is $_REQUEST['name'] and $email is $_REQUEST['email'], but I strip out all "\r" and "\n" if any because they can put `"\r\nCc:<a list of emails>"` and they would be able to send spam emails using my domain.

However, for an input I mentioned above, I don't see 'newline' under 'email' field. Hence, I assume it is a different kind of attack.
Is there something I should be aware of?

Comment: I used to receive a lot of these spam comments, all with random links. I figured it is probably some kind of test run.

Answer (score 2):

> Hence, I assume it is a different kind of attack.

I doubt it. This doesn't look like an E-Mail injection attack, but a simple run-off-the-mill bot trying to get its content linked in as many places (e.g. comment threads) as possible. That's why the `[link]`  notation is there, to cause the URL to be linked in BBCode.

Except from that it's trash, I can see nothing malicious in the message.

To stop this, as others say, captcha solutions are the most popular way; there are others. See the related questions on SO, e.g. [Blocking comment spam without using captcha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577918/blocking-comment-spam-without-using-captcha)

Comment: Thank you for your response. CAPTCHA was an option for me until I figured it decreased the number of contact from users (maybe due to small friction where users have to type in CAPTCHA). It is just weird to me that this bot is trying to get its content linked in many places since the content is pure junk. The URL also does not lead to anywhere.