# post php form to .asp function

Tags: php, forms, asp-classic

I am looking at a website for a friend, to resolve his spam issue with one of his forms.

the form is posted to a website using PHP to an .ASP function, the issue i have is i an trying to apply hunnypot captcha, but am having trouble with PHP function.

i was wondering if some one could point me in the right direction please.

here is the form

```
// Usage: [form]form action URL here[/form]
function form_func( $atts, $content = null ) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'action' => '',
    ), $atts));
    return '<div class="text-center"><strong>Apply Now with this easy form</strong></div>
<form id="contact-form" action="'.do_shortcode($content).'" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
  <ul>
    <li><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name:" id="name" value="" /></li>
    <li><input type="tel" name="phone" placeholder="Telephone Number:" id="phone" value="" /></li>
    <li><input type="text" name="post-code" placeholder="Post Code:" id="post-code" value="" /></li>
    <li><input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email:" value="" /></li>
    <li class="email2"><input type="email" name="repeatemail" id="repeatemail" placeholder="Email:" value="" /></li>
  </ul>
  <input type="submit" value="Send" />

</form>';
}
```

this is where it is being sent to

```
http://www.bigresponder.com/remote_contact.asp?si=563&p=494225795
```

and here is the PHP i have started

```
if($_POST['repeatemail'] != ''){
    echo "It appears you are a bot!";
}
else{
//process the rest of the form
}
```

and this is the css

```
li.email2{display:none;}
```

i have applied this to the form, but the spam is still getting through, so obviously i am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Good Day, you must check this out first, [Blocking comment spam without using captcha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577918/blocking-comment-spam-without-using-captcha)

the most commons solution is using captcha on the form and validate it into asp sender if you can access code 
http://www.captcha.net/
http://sweetcaptcha.com/

Comment: Hi, thank you for you reply, I have looked at the different forms of captcha a number of times, but the owner of the website doesn't want something visible, hence forth why I was looking at hunnypot captcha, it is a WordPress site, and was a little unsure as to what function posted the form, I think I have found it, but what I am unsure how else to post it to the http address, can I apply that address in the post function?

Comment: you´re welcome, if is a wordpress i suggest you see this, http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress  and try to replace contact form with a plugin -> https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=contact

Comment: Hi, OK thank you I'll take a look, would using a plugin form still give me the function to post to the URL address?