# Is it possible to detect crawler besides user agent?

Tags: apache, web-crawler

Following scenario:

Some kind of crawler asserts he uses Firefox for example

> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/29.0

Am I able to detect that this *user* is **not** using a browser?

### Why I want to do this

I found a user with an odd behaviour in my apache logs but I don't want to ban him unless I know this is a crawler

Comment: Some crawlers feed search engines.  Search engines bring visitors.

Comment: @Paul I don't think a serchengine crawler claims to be firefox

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233192/detecting-stealth-web-crawlers), or at least related

Answer (score 0):

Some crawlers are designed to mimic normal UI-based user agents, so there's no really good way to circumvent that. You can implement all kinds of hacks to circumvent crawlers. Typically things that are javascript based.

As the related link shows, stealthy crawlers will try to be stealthy and pretend to be an actual UI. So even if you employ Javascript hacks for example, a good crawler can embed some Javascript engine to parse the links properly. It's a constant game of cat and mouse.