# How to Stop bad crawler from crawling

Tags: php, web-crawler, scrapy

So, I have an eshop (php), and noticed that some competitors are always changing their prices to be lower that mine. I think that they are crawling my website for prices. Is there any way to stop that?

I think that one of the solutions would be to block crawlers IP, but I don't know which IP it is.

Could I block it if there are too many request?

Comment: Use for example GoAccess to analyze you web logs, and then throw 404 to crawlers :)

Comment: You can try to block by invalid user-agents, but that is a losing battle. Any web client can change the user agent. Also, what makes you think they are crawling your website?

Comment: Just check you access logs - any scrapeing activity should be easy to spot. Then bad the associated IPs. However the real problem is a business model one, not a programming one.

Comment: Crawl the competitor's website in return :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting 'stealth' web-crawlers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/233192/detecting-stealth-web-crawlers)

Answer (score 0):

Think about enabling reCAPTCHA for your Website, see e.g. https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html